# Bisection algorithm for negative square roots

Tags: python, infinite-loop

I have a bisection loop for positive integer square roots.  When attempting a negative square root, it gets caught in an infinite loop. I've narrowed it down to it setting ans to -12 and then squaring it, but I can't figure out how to fix the loop so it stays in. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code in question below:

```
x = -25
epsilon = 0.01
numGuesses = 0
low = 1.0
high = x
ans = (high + low)/2.0
if x >= 1.0:
    while abs(ans**2 - x) >= epsilon:
        print("low = " + str(low) + " high + " + str(high) + " ans = " + str(ans))
        numGuesses += 1
        if ans**2 < x:
            low = ans
        else:
            high = ans
        ans = (high + low)/2.0
else:       
    while abs(ans**2 - x) >= epsilon:
        print("low = " + str(low) + " high + " + str(high) + " ans = " + str(ans))
        numGuesses += 1
        if abs(ans**2) < x:
            low = ans

        else:
            high = ans
        ans = (high + low)/2.0

print("numGuesses = " + str(numGuesses))
print(str(ans) + " is close to square root of " + str(x))
```

Comment: Uh... do you know anything about the properties of squaring and square roots? There's something rather fundamental you seem to be missing...

Comment: You realize that you need complex arithmetic to take the square root of a negative number, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer that I ended up with thanks to Prune is as follows:

```
x = -25
if x < 0:
    flag = False
else:
    flag = True 
if flag is False:
    x = abs(x)

epsilon = 0.01
numGuesses = 0
low = 1.0
high = x
ans = (high + low)/2.0
if x >= 1.0:
    while abs(ans**2 - x) >= epsilon:
        print("low = " + str(low) + " high + " + str(high) + " ans = " + str(ans))
        numGuesses += 1
        if ans**2 < x:
            low = ans
        else:
            high = ans
        ans = (high + low)/2.0

if flag is False:
    ans = -ans
    x = -x    
print("numGuesses = " + str(numGuesses))
print(str(ans) + " is close to square root of " + str(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to set a `sign` flag: flip `x` to positive, set `sign = False` and then find the sqrt of +25.  When you converge, check `sign`: if it's `False`, then your value is imaginary.

Your current code is trying to converge to a real root, and that's *never* going to work for a negative number.

Comment: Thank you so much!

It took a bit of googling to figure out exactly what you meant and how to do it, but I got it working thanks to you.

Comment: Glad to be of help ... and to have prompted you to find some new knowledge.  BTW, there are `complex` number packages available for Python; look those up when you get the chance.  They might help if you need to code something for quadratic equations in a month or two.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Comment: I up-voted and accepted the answer you posted, but my rep is too low to give you a publicly score boost.

Comment: Don't worry: keep reading, keep posting, stay active here, and learn.  I was thinking you might want to write a complete answer, post it yourself, and accept *that*.

Comment: Also, note that you don't really have to split the cases at 1.0 ... the algorithm will converge on either side.

Comment: I did as you suggested although I can't accept my answer for 2 more days apparently.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = -37
epsilon = 0.01
num_guess = 0
low = 0.0
high = abs(x)

ans = ((low + high)/2.0)

while abs(ans**3-abs(x)) >= epsilon:
    #print("low = " + str(low) + " high " + str(high) + " ans = " + str(ans))
    if ans**3 < abs(x):
        low = ans
    else :
        high = ans
    ans = ((low + high)/2.0)
    num_guess += 1 

if x < 0:
    ans = -ans
print("Steps taken during bisecction search: ",num_guess)
print("The cube root of " + str(x) + " is " + str(ans))
```

maybe you can just print abs() in all the x's you have inputted in the code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was *how to fix the loop so it stays in?* The simple answer is: **you don't**.

The approach to solve this problem is partly mathematical and partly software design.

Mathematically you cannot calculate the square root of a negative number and get a real number as a result. There are two possible solutions:

1. Switch to complex numbers. But I doubt that your bisection algorithm will work then.
2. When you do not need complex numbers or when your problem domain cannot make sense of complex results then **do not perform the calculation for negative numbers.**

What you should **never** do is to write code that produces a result for negative numbers. Of course, algorithmically you can do so, as several answers, including your own, show.  But it is a very bad idea, for the following software design considerations.

Your code will be part of a larger software and there will be some other code that will be calling your function. Mathematics gives you a hint here: calling your function with a negative number is a **fault on the callers side**. But since your function will return *some* (mathematically useless) result such a kind of fault in your software project may be left uncovered for a long, long time. But some day it will produce ugly failures, warm and comfortably hidden in the hazes you created to make it tremendously difficult to find it.

Ok, sorry, the solution is: **raise an exception when your function is called with a negative argument**.